# Android | Failed to install apk manually after debug

Tags: android

I use Android studio to develop my app and I install it as debug on my emulators and smartphone. It works, but if I would to install manually the release apk, it doesn't work. I get an error: app not installed.
If I unistall the debug version and then I install the release apk, it works.

I use Instant Run. This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.mypackage.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        //incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    /*lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }*/
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2' //entry
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0' //fab DEPRECATED
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:arclayout:1.0.2' //arc layout
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7' //animated imageview

    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1' //fit textview
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13' //color picker
    implementation 'com.github.zagum:Android-SwitchIcon:1.3.5' //switch icon
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5' //custom toast
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.4.1' //zoom image view

}
```

Comment: It is because debug and release keystores are different, so android system refuse to install the same package with another keystore

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've the same problem if I try to install the release apk on an emulator when I previously installed the app from the play store. Is it the same problem? Can I use the same keystore? How?

Answer (score 0):

**Probable Causes**

1) The phone might be out of disk space.

2) The app after install might be making the phone go out of space.

3) The app needs to be uninstalled for all users if not done do that; it is observed in most of the Android API 27 i.e. Oreo 8.0 devices or VMs.